# A "canonical" question of ours is terrible. What should we do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7174/difference-between-ui-and-ux/ is an extremely important question, but it's an old cast off from Stack Overflow and has been (mostly) answered by Programmers, not Designers. It was migrated here after it was a dead thread.

The [accepted answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7174/difference-between-ui-and-ux/7175#7175) shows the inherent problem...on a site for user experience design, the "accepted" definition of UI/UX starts with "So it seems like....". Most of the other answers were from programmers and the asker (who accepted a meh answer) is long gone and doesn't even have an account here.

This is an important question and a *good* version would be a great resource to point people too. Is it worth reasking and closing this question as a dupe? Or should we Community Wiki and fix the answer where it is? Or is it not worth fussing with at all?

Answer (score 11):

In these cases I think we should close/delete and reask because it gives people the opportunity to answer it and get the full reputation. Just going in and editing someone else's stuff doesn't inspire the same motivation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of trying to hammer this one into a good post

Comment: I agree although a re-ask definitely might cause a batch of answers to sift through, hopefully they would all be of better quality. That'd be a great rep booster to be the one re-asking that question on here haha.

Comment: What about reopening this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13475/what-is-difference-between-ui-and-ux. Or, inviting the one answer to repost in the new question?